# how to split ntext datatype data to store in database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a column of type `ntext` called `Emp_details_list`, and it consists of data like

```
 emp1#@#emp2#@#emp3...
```

At most it has 20 thousand characters as string and I am storing in that column and I need to split it and save in other table `EmpDet` and in other column (`Single_Emp_det`) but while splitting I can't cast `ntext` as `nvarchar` so am using a local variable and declared as  `nvarchar(max)` and splitting but I can store only 8000 character only if I have 8001 characters it showing exception because it can't store so how can I store whole `ntext` data in other column using splitting concept in SQL Server

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Why are you using `ntext` instead of `nvarchar(max)`?

Comment: `nvarchar(max)` can store **up to 2 GB** of data - definitely **a lot more** than 8000 characters...

Comment: can u please let me know the exact number of characters which can store in nvarchar(max)?

Answer (score 0):

So you are probably stuck with Sql server 2000. If you can't use nvarchar(max), one possible way is to may be use substring function and copy your ntext to manageable chunks of varchar(8000) in a loop. In each iteration, save the 'part of chunk after the last #', to be used in next iteration. So you basically loop over your table, within that loop again loop over the ntext field value in chunks of 8k and do the rest. Hope it is clear enough.

Comment: As now i am using sql server 2005 and i am using ntext datatype. the string which am sending to db is more than 20thousand characters so am using ntext bec ntext can easily stores it where as nvarchar(max) can store only 8thousand characters as i know so to over come from that problem am using ntext @Aaron Bertrand

Comment: it is little bit difficult to add delimiter aft 8000 character can u explain how can i added delimiter after 8000character in db and my dough is how can i cum to know number characters in a string  in sqlserver2005 is der any thing to find?Thnk u very much for ur supportive answer.pls help me @Brian

Comment: @MounikaReddy - Not sure where you got the idea that nvarchar(max) has 8000 characters limit. It doesn't. Your 20K is easily handled by nvarchar(max). You have no problem with nvarchar(max). Try it.

Answer (score 0):

As others already mentioned you can easily store 20000 characters in nvarchar(max). You are probably doing something wrong when converting these types.

Here is an example of converting from and to nvarchar(max) that clearly shows how can you store 20000 characters there.

```
DECLARE @v1 nvarchar(max)

DECLARE @v2 nvarchar(max)



create table #textExample

(

    id int,

    t1 ntext

)



declare @count int

set @v1 = ''

SET @count = 0

while @count < 20000

begin  

   set @v1 = @v1 + '1'

   set @count = @count + 1

end

--converting nvarchar(max) to ntext

insert into #textExample

values (1, CONVERT(ntext,@v1))



select * from #textExample

-- converting ntext back to nvarchar(max)

SET @v2 = CONVERT(nvarchar(max), (select t1 from #textExample where id = 1))

select @v2, LEN(@v2)





drop table #textExample
```